# How to create a jquery array that contains variables as key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array

```
query = { x: { y: z } }
```

I tried like this but jquery makes my vars as constant key

```
var x = "one";
var y = "two";
var z = "three";

var query = { x: { y: z } }
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `{...}` is an Object; `[...]` is an Array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to achieve that.

```
var query = {}, obj = {}; // objects
obj[y] = z; 
query[x] = obj;
console.log(query);
```

Comment: @Younisbarznji glad it worked.. do mark any answer as answer by clicking the tick mark which helped you the most

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var query; 
query[x]={};
query[x][y]=z;
```

Comment: There's a syntax error. You should test your code before posting an answer.

Comment: Sorry, just missed the line for variable declaration. I've made the change.

Comment: thank you also your code is working with a little update
i make it like this and it was fine

var query{}; 
query[x]={};
query[x][y]=z;

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to create a hashtable and use some variables as keys. You can do this by creating a hashtable and then setting values as follows

```
var query = {},
    x = 'one',
    y = 'two',
    z = 'three';

query[x] = {};
query[x][y] = z
```